# Cisco ASA creating two identicial Tunnel IDs?

Tags: cisco-asa, tunnel, fortigate, fortinet, l2vpn

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I have a Cisco ASA peering with a Forigate to create  VPN Site-to-Site Tunnel. The odd thing is I see this in ASDM, the Cisco ASA is creating two(2) identical tunnel IDs? Furthermore, bringing up the Tunnel will only work if a host on the Cisco ASA network initiates a connection through the Tunnel, not the other way around.
[image: Cisco ASDM Identical Tunnel IDs?]

**Basic Info is 2 networks with ACLs allowing ICMP and IP**

- Cisco ASA hosts -- 10.10.0.0/255.255.224.0
- Forigate hosts -- 10.255.255.0/255.255.255.0
- Phase 1 and Phase 2 show complete on both Cisco ASA and Fortigate.

Has anyone come accross this before with the identical Tunnel IDs?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, they aren't identical: 1718.1, 1718.2, 1718.3

There will be one security association ("tunnel") per ACL rule.